# Where is Sphinx located after I install it?

Tags: rails

I have to install Sphinx on my Ubuntu 11.10 for it to work on a ruby app.

I managed to install it through synaptics, however when I run my sphinx (`rake ts:rebuild`) I get an error message saying:

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
* bin_path
* searchd_binary_name
* indexer_binary_name
```

I guess I just need to edit the `sphinx.yml` file with the right info but hey, I can't seem to find out where sphinx is. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
which searchd
which indexer
```